# How to display both an RGB and a grascale image in the same figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rgb, grayscale, figure

I have two things to show in the same figure: a [surf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) plot and a grayscale image. They must be shown in the same figure, and the plot must be in colour. If I show the plot first and step through the code, the plot is displayed in colour just fine, but the moment the grayscale image is shown, everything turns to grascale.

Note: I have tried changing the colour map, but it also changes the grayscale image. Is there any way to just have the plot in colour?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
surf(data), shading interp;
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(grayimg);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Matlab supports only one colormap per figure, you are trying to use two: `gray` for the image and `jet` for the surfplot.

A workaround is to trick Matlab to believe the image is in color ;)

```
figure;
subplot(1,2,1); surf(data); shading interp;
subplot(1,2,2); imshow( grayimg(:,:,[1 1 1]) ); % this is the trick: you convert one channel image to RGB image with all pixels shades of gray...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification and the trick, makes perfect sense now! You're a lifesaver.